# Is it possible to define an MTD partition with a "hole" for another partition?

Tags: linux, partition, flash-memory

I'm working with a Xilinx Linux kernel and u-boot, which expects the u-boot boot script to be located at 0x3e80000-0x4000000.  For Xilinx's devkits this is the end of the 64 MiB NOR flash, but I'm using a much larger (256 MiB) flash and want to place a complete rootfs in an UBIFS partition that u-boot can read directly (rather than have a separate "kernel" partition with a bunch of redundant information).  So, normally the partitions look like:

```
        partition@0 {
            label = "boot";
            reg = <0x0 0x1000000>;
        };
        partition@1000000 {
            label = "kernel";
            reg = <0x1000000 0x2E80000>;
        };
        partition@3e80000 {
            label = "bootscr";
            reg = <0x3e80000 0x180000>;
        };
```

and I would like to have something like this:

```
        partition@0 {
            label = "boot";
            reg = <0x0 0x1000000>;
        };
        partition@1000000 {
            label = "ubi-1";
            reg = <0x1000000 0x2E80000>;
        };
        partition@3e80000 {
            label = "bootscr";
            reg = <0x3e80000 0x180000>;
        };
        partition@4000000 {
            label = "ubi-2";
            reg = <0x4000000 0x8000000>;
        };
```

where I can use the `ubi-1` and `ubi-2` partitions to create a single UBIFS volume.  Is there a way to do this?  The UBIFS system seems to expect a single MTD partition to sit on top of, otherwise I would just give it both partitions.  Is there possibly a way to declare one partition with a "hole" for the boot script partition?